# React-360 camera position in view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-360

I want to set my camera view higher compared to a rendered view. But I don't know where I could set the intial camera position when rendering a view.

My component is mounted like this:

```
import {ReactInstance} from 'react-360-web';

function init(bundle, parent, options = {}) {
  const r360 = new ReactInstance(bundle, parent, {
    // Add custom options here
    fullScreen: true,
    ...options,
  });

  // Render your app content to the default cylinder surface
  r360.renderToSurface(
    r360.createRoot('Hello360', { /* initial props */ }),
    r360.getDefaultSurface()
  );
}

window.React360 = {init};
```

And the component looks like this:

```
export default class Hello360 extends React.Component {
  // Our component will keep track of this state
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.panel}>
        <View style={styles.greetingBox}>
          <Text style={styles.greeting}>
            Hello React
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.greeting}>
            {`Count: ${this.state.count}`}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  panel: {
    // Fill the entire surface
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Hello360', () => Hello360);
```

I tried adding the transform attribute to the styles element but this doesn't work. How can I change the camera position relative to the mounted Hello360 component in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the camera position higher like this (inside init in client.js):

```
r360._cameraPosition = [0, 3, 0]; //[x, y, z], default ist [0, 0, 0]
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-360/blob/master/React360/js/ReactInstance.js

Comment: how can I call this from within a component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255894/react-360-render-to-location-from-component/50258189